# gatsby зависает develop сборка на IMAGE_PROCESSING

Tags: javascript, node.js, gatsbyjs

Процесс сборки зависает на моменте Running gatsby-plugin-sharp.IMAGE_PROCESSING jobs

```
  System:
    OS: macOS 12.4
    CPU: (12) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-9750H CPU @ 2.60GHz
    Shell: 5.8.1 - /bin/zsh
  Binaries:
    Node: 16.14.2 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v16.14.2/bin/node
    npm: 8.10.0 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v16.14.2/bin/npm
  Browsers:
    Safari: 15.5
  npmPackages:
    gatsby: ^4.14.1 => 4.15.0
    gatsby-plugin-image: ^2.14.1 => 2.15.0
    gatsby-plugin-manifest: ^4.14.0 => 4.15.0
    gatsby-plugin-react-helmet: ^5.14.0 => 5.15.0
    gatsby-plugin-sass: ^5.14.0 => 5.15.0
    gatsby-plugin-sharp: ^4.14.1 => 4.15.0
    gatsby-plugin-sitemap: ^5.14.0 => 5.15.0
    gatsby-source-filesystem: ^4.14.0 => 4.15.0
    gatsby-transformer-sharp: ^4.14.0 => 4.15.0

success compile gatsby files - 0.810s
success load gatsby config - 0.045s
success load plugins - 1.157s
success onPreInit - 0.006s
success initialize cache - 0.130s
success copy gatsby files - 0.143s
success Compiling Gatsby Functions - 0.328s
success onPreBootstrap - 0.352s
success createSchemaCustomization - 3.485s
success Checking for changed pages - 0.001s
success source and transform nodes - 0.164s
success building schema - 0.242s
not finished createPages - 75736.903s
not finished Running gatsby-plugin-sharp.IMAGE_PROCESSING jobs - 75716.723s
```

где можно посмотреть логи или понять что происходит? просто виснет на этом моменте, при этом build проходит успешно, clean не помогает

```
⠏ createPages
[============================]   37.377 s 309/309 100% Running gatsby-plugin-sharp.IMAGE_PROCESSING jobs
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

решил проблему тупо поменяв сеть или используя впн, видимо роутер сяоми косячит